# Gif performance vs Animation performance

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there a performance difference between animations and gifs?

I mean why should I use sizeTransition instead of using a gif with the same effect?

Comment: Do you mean `gif` files with format `.gif`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gifs are low quality, low framerate, hight RAM consumption.

While animations don't have these limitations.